# using mechanize and got the uninitialized constant Object::WWW (NameError)

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm using mechanize in windows 7 x64 OS, but got the the uninitialized constant Object::WWW (NameError),

the code is very simple:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
```

error occurs at the line `agent = WWW::Mechanize.new`

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

remove the WWW:: - that got removed a long time ago.

Comment: thanks... i found some code online and used it as it is.. your suggestions fixed the issue..

Answer (score 0):

While googling found the following code, may be useful to you.

```
@a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
      agent.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; es-ES; rv:1.9
.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/6.0.2'
    }
@a.get("http://www.somesite.com"]) do |page|
      page.search("//a[id='id-name']"]).each do |a|
      puts a
end
```